# MySql extract data from a database based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I Am trying to create/run an my sql query in such a way that the sql selects data based a some conditions from Column 1 (USER) but at the same time Excludes some data, based on some conditions from column 2 (ADDRESS)

E.g.:

```
SELECT ADDRESS,USER
FROM Data1.Table1
WHERE FIELD(USER,'%AMIT%','%JOHN%','%SANDEEP%','%WARNE%')
  AND ORIGINATING_ADDRESS NOT LIKE 'MUMBAI','CHINA','PAKISTAN'
```

This is giving error.Can some one please help ?

Comment: `... AND ORIGINATING_ADDRESS NOT IN ('MUMBAI','CHINA','PAKISTAN')`

Comment: If you get an error, at least tell us the error message

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT IN` to discard list of values from `select`. Considering that you want to discard when there is exact match

```
ORIGINATING_ADDRESS NOT IN ('MUMBAI','CHINA','PAKISTAN')
```

When you want to use pattern search and discard the use this

```
ORIGINATING_ADDRESS NOT LIKE '%MUMBAI%' OR 
ORIGINATING_ADDRESS NOT LIKE '%CHINA%' OR      
ORIGINATING_ADDRESS NOT LIKE '%PAKISTAN%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For a set of values, use `NOT IN`, instead of `NOT LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find regular expressions simpler for this purpose:

```
SELECT ADDRESS,USER
FROM Data1.Table1
WHERE USER REGEXP 'AMIT|JOHN|SANDEEP|WARNE' AND
      ORIGINATING_ADDRESS NOT REGEXP 'MUMBAI|CHINA|PAKISTAN';
```

Comment: Sir,you have stated both as NOT ?

Comment: @SanjayDutta . . . I missed that detail.  The first should not have the `NOT`.